# I want to find correlation between two list, and each list has two array. I wrote a code for this but find the value error. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, correlation

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
LP_obs = np.loadtxt(fname = "D:\Python_dir\LP_obs.txt")
LP_sim = np.loadtxt(fname = "D:\Python_dir\LP_sim.txt")
LP_obs_1 = np.loadtxt(fname = "D:\Python_dir\LP_obs_1.txt")
LP_sim_1 = np.loadtxt(fname = "D:\Python_dir\LP_sim_1.txt")

def rsquared(x, y):   
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
    return r_value**2

list1=[]
list2=[]
list1.append((LP_obs,LP_obs_1)) 
list2.append((LP_sim,LP_sim_1))

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:    
        R=rsquared(i,j)
q=[]
q.append(R)
print(q)
```

I input data from a .txt file. After running the code I got the error:

```
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py", line 116, in linregress
ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is your scipy version?

Comment: Short version of my answer - show the **traceback**, and review your `for` loops carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line (which you don't show):

```
ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
```

On the left you have 4 variables.  The error says that `np.cov(....).flat`
produces more than 4 values (`flat` is a `numpy.flatiter`)

What does `np.cov(...)` produce?  According to the docs?  According your your own code tests?   These are things you should be checking!

If this `cov` call isn't part of your code, then you need to show the **whole** traceback.

===

Looking at the functions I see that `np.cov(x,y)` is called by `scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)`, which in turn is called via `rsquared(i,j)`

Tells us about the `i,j` that you are passing.

This block of code looks suspicious.

Why the append to an empty list?  Have you looked at `list1` after this?  Does the `i,j` that you sent to `rquared` look right?

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
list1.append((LP_obs,LP_obs_1)) 
list2.append((LP_sim,LP_sim_1))

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:    
        R=rsquared(i,j)
q=[]
q.append(R)
print(q)
```

And what's with the `q` append, that's outside of the for loops?  You only do that append once, using the **last** `R`.  You aren't accumulating those `R` values.

Comment: Looks like the last trace is from scipy and not the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, std_err = scipy.stats.mstats.linregress(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the appended part of the code

```
list1.append(LP_obs)  
list1.append(LP_obs_1)  
list2.append(LP_sim)  
list2.append(LP_sim_1)
```

I think you are getting the error because you have appended tuple of two lists which make it as 2-D. I think function does not accept 2-D arrays as input. I hope by doing this you will get the correct required answer.

If above does not solve your problem try this:

can't you just concatenate the two 1-D arrays and do this

```
a1 = np.concatenate((LP_obs,LP_obs_1))
a2 = np.concatenate((LP_sim,LP_sim_1))

def rsquared(x, y):   
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
    return r_value**2

R=rsquared(a1,a2)
q=[]
q.append(R)
print(q)
```

if this is not your required, say for which lists you want to find the r-value?

Comment: sorry, it did not work. Actually I have two lists and each has two 1D arrays. I want to find R-value for the two lists. Would you like to help me to do this?